# Why are AsyncTask threads running one after the other?

Tags: android, sdk

I am offloading many background operations (like web access, and DB operations) to AsyncTasks in order to make my application run faster. It partially works, because the UI does not hang. But it still takes the app a long time to settle (i.e. finish the background tasks).

When looking at the logcat I noticed that all the background tasks (AsyncTask) run one after the other. No concurrency. How can one write a truly multi-threaded application?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the AsyncTask's documentation you can see that indeed Android runs all non-main-thread tasks in a single thread. See "order of execution" in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

But there you also have the solution: use  [executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Comment: You should just do your background work in Threads if you don't want to wait until one finishes.  AsyncTask threads will always run one after another.

Comment: You are right, Xjasz, if the only purpose was to run a long task. But I use these (short) AsyncTasks to update the UI. I run many queries, and calculations against my backend (fetch images, update stats, etc.) that update the UI independently of each other.

For this purpose exactly you have AsyncTasks. The fact that Google decided to serialize all the background tasks is not because it is a better platform design, but because it broke many legacy apps. And now, when the average phone has 4 cores, going up to 8, it is a shame that Android is masquerading the useful AsyncTask features.

Comment: What's your problem then?  If you want to update the ui from a Thread just do create a handler or RunOnUI.  I was always annoyed with AsncTask when trying to update the UI.  Ever since I learned how Handlers and RunOnUi it made my life much easier.  I can throw together a simple method if you want.

Comment: For some cases spawning a background thread, and calling runOnUiThread once in a while is a good practice. But in some other cases, where the tasks are not related to each other, the AsyncTask comes in handy. I am not trying to cover all design patterns in this question, just to elaborate on AsyncTask - which I still find handy :-)